# Can't connect to Internet on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, network-adapter, wifi-driver

I can't connect to WiFi, even though I have WiFi in my house. I've tried downloading new drivers and it just says:

> Not connected - no connections available

I checked the device properties and it says:

> Device install requested
>
> Device PCI
>   \VEN_8086&DEV_0886&SUBSYS_13158086&REV_67\4&2387eb&0&00E1 requires further installation.

The network adapter is "Intel Centrino Wireless-N 6150".

I recently installed Linux Mint 18 as a dual boot with Windows 10, I could connect to wifi on linux, but windows wouldn't connect. So I uninstalled linux and nothing seemed to change. I also reset Windows and still nothing changed.

Please help.

Comment: Try this http://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-no-wifi-available-after-windows-10-update.html

Comment: @CodeIt this didn't work, but thanks for helping anyways

Answer (score 1):

If you have mentioned the model of your Wi-Fi module correctly then it is not supported under Windows 10. The latest version of [Windows it supports is 8.1](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/59476/Intel-Centrino-Wireless-N-WiMAX-6150-Single-Band).

You can try [downloading driver for Windows 8.1](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25200/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Windows-8-1-?product=59476) and installing it in compatibility mode for 8.1. But it is not guaranteed that this option will work.

Comment: I already tried that, I think I'm just gonna take it to a it place and see what they can do, and if they cant figure it out, ill just get linux again